# Connect Arduino with ROS (Ubuntu) via wifi

Tags: ros, arduino, wifi

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello i have previously connected my ROS (Ubuntu) with an arduino uno via bluetooth and publish data from the arduino and view it by using rostopic echo but now i want to do the same thing but by using wifi i want to connect my arduino with a wifi router and communicate with ROS via wifi how can i do that... i seriously need help to get my project done

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/238648/connect-arduino-with-ros-(ubuntu)-via-wifi/) by [naqi.nick](https://answers.ros.org/users/25464/naqi.nick/) on ROS Answers with karma: 62 on 2016-07-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

If you plan to use WiFi you will have to make sure that you can ping all components on the network. In other words, properly set up your network. I would say there must be a set up guide for the Arduino/shield on the web to do so.

Then, start sending UDP packages (or the protocol that suits your application)  from your Arduino to one node in ROS.

Cheers

---

Originally posted by [Nexus8](https://answers.ros.org/users/26736/nexus8/) with karma: 106 on 2016-07-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0